# helm search not listing packages but installing in GKE kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, kubernetes-helm

I have installed `helm` on a `GKE Cluster`. Installation is fine

```
$ helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.2.4", GitCommit:"0ad800ef43d3b826f31a5ad8dfbb4fe05d143688", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.12"}
```

I am able to install `MySQL/MariaDB` using `helm` successfully using below command

```
helm install stable/mysql
helm install  stable/mariadb
```

But when I try to search these packages, I could not find the package

```
$ helm search  hub mysql
No results found
$ helm search  hub mariadb
No results found
```

While listing publicly available charts by running `helm search hub`, it gives below output

```
$ helm search hub
NAME                    CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION
stable/hubot            1.0.1           3.3.2           Hubot chatbot for Slack
stable/eventrouter      0.3.0           0.3             A Helm chart for eventruter (https://github.com/heptiolab...
stable/mercure          4.0.1           0.10.0          The Mercure hub allows to push data updates using the Mer...
stable/oauth2-proxy     3.2.0           5.1.0           A reverse proxy that provides authentication with Google,...`
```

I think my understanding is wrong. Can somebody please explain why the package is not listed with the `helm search` command?

Comment: It almost seems like your searches are running `helm 2` instead of `helm 3`. With helm 2 `search hub mysql` would not work correctly, but in helm 3 it seems to work fine. Are all of the above commands run from the same machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encounter similar issue.

As you are using `Helm 3` I skip installation part. My solution was to add proper google repository:

```
$ helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
"stable" has been added to your repositories

$ helm repo update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "incubator" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈
```

**Output:**

```
$ helm search  hub mariadb
URL                                                     CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/mariadb-galera       4.0.0           10.5.4          MariaDB Galera is a multi-master database clust...
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/mariadb-cluster      1.0.1           10.2.14         Chart to create a Highly available MariaDB cluster
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/phpmyadmin           6.2.2           5.0.2           phpMyAdmin is an mysql administration frontend
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/mariadb              7.6.1           10.3.23         Fast, reliable, scalable, and easy to use open-...
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/ibm-charts/ibm-galer...      1.1.0                           Galera Cluster is a multi-master solution for M...
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/ibm-charts/ibm-maria...      1.1.2                           MariaDB is developed as open source software an...
user@cloudshell:~ (k8s-tests-278413)$

$ helm search  hub mysql
URL                                                     CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/cetic/adminer                0.1.3           4.7.6           Adminer is a full-featured database management ...
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/t3n/cloudsql-proxy           2.0.0           1.16            Google Cloud SQL Proxy
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/t3n/mysql-backup             2.0.0
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/mariadb-galera       4.0.0           10.5.4          MariaDB Galera is a multi-master database clust...
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/mysql                6.14.4          8.0.20          Chart to create a Highly available MySQL cluster
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/mariadb-cluster      1.0.1           10.2.14         Chart to create a Highly available MariaDB cluster
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/phpmyadmin           6.2.2           5.0.2           phpMyAdmin is an mysql administration frontend
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/bitnami/mariadb              7.6.1           10.3.23         Fast, reliable, scalable, and easy to use open-...
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/softonic/mysql-backup        2.1.4           0.2.0           Take mysql backups from any mysql instance to A...
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/rimusz/gcloud-sqlproxy       0.19.12         1.16            Google Cloud SQL Proxy
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/kanister/kanister-mysql      0.31.0          5.7.14          MySQL w/ Kanister support based on stable/mysql
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/appscode/stash-mysql         8.0.14          8.0.14          stash-mysql - MySQL database backup and restore...
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/presslabs/mysql-cluster      0.2.0           1.0             A Helm chart for easy deployment of a MySQL clu...
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/presslabs/mysql-oper...      0.4.0           v0.4.0          A Helm chart for mysql operator
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/presslabs/orchestrator       0.1.7           3.0.14          A Helm chart for github's mysql orchestrator
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/incubator/mysqlha            2.0.0           5.7.13          MySQL cluster with a single master and zero or ...
https://hub.helm.sh/charts/wso2/mysql-am                3.1.0-2         5.7             A 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [helm hub](https://hub.helm.sh) to search for any chart such as nginx and you can use the command given there to install the chart. Please note

1. Not all charts are available in `stable` repo
2. You need to update local helm repo to be able to install the chart.

   `helm repo update`

   `helm install stable/nginx-ingress`